# long running timeout callbacks prevent requestAnimationFrame callbacks from executing

Tags: javascript, callback, timeout, requestanimationframe, event-loop

I've watched [Jake Archibald talk about event loop](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1656) and learnt that there are 3 queues in the browser:

- callback queue
- microtask queue
- animation queue

that behave differently when it comes to executing their items.

Callback queue executes callback one at a time, meaning that after executing a callback the browser checks if there are other things to do (like rerendering the page) before proceeding to the next one.

Microtask queue executes its items till the queue is empty (which may lead to infinite blocking)

Animation queue is for `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks and it also executes its items till the queue is empty apart from callbacks that were added in one of currently executed callbacks (those are executed at next frame).

I wanted to check that and created a script that recursively invoked `requestAnimationFrame` and queued 50 timeout callbacks that blocked main thread for 15ms.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    block(15);
    console.log(`timeout ${i}`)
  })
}

const startDate = Date.now();
function raf() {
  requestAnimationFrame((x) => {
    if (Date.now() < startDate + 1000) {
      console.log(`raf ${x}`)
      raf();
    }
  })
}

raf();



function block(ms) {
  const startDate = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() < startDate + ms) { }
}
```

live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xdpbbb?file=index.js

Since the block time is roughly equal to the time between frames (60fps gives 16.666ms) I was expecting a intertwining pattern between raf and timeout callbacks. But the result was completely different:

[image: results]

As you can see there are around 10 timeout callback between raf callbacks that take around 150ms to finish. Why isn't it like:

1. timeout cb
2. animation cb
3. timeout cb
4. animation cb
   ?

Comment: You have not given your timeouts any timeout value, so all your doing is running 50 wait functions before it even calls your first `raf`, try at least putting a `1` in your timeout..

Comment: @Keith callbacks are executed after at least 4.7 milliseconds -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified. Anyway, the rafs should fire in roughly16ms from each other but they are clearly not.

Comment: I think you might find -> `while (Date.now() < startDate + ms)` is not going to give you very accurate timing..  Firefox for example -> `by default and defaults to 20us in Firefox 59; in 60 it will be 2ms.`  IOW: latest browsers you have 2 ms,..  So I would say the `clearly not`, needs more proof..

Comment: @Keith when you look at the picture you can see that timer code takes around 15ms (it's the screenshot from performance tab in chrome dev tools) so it is legit. You can run the code yourself (check live demo link above) and see the results.

Comment: I'm really not sure what problem your trying to solve, but your creating 50 timers that are going to to block the main thread for 15ms each, JS is single threaded, so why would you expect requestAnimationFrame to be able to fire every 4ms..?

Comment: @Keith first, raf should fire before a frame which in devices with 60fps is roughly 16ms. If you remove timeout code you'll see that raf cb is called every 16ms. I expect that the browser before calling each of those timer cbs check if there's something else to do (and it has something to do since there is raf cb waiting to execute). But the browser gets sloppy and executes rafs much rarely than it should. I want to know why.

Comment: `browser gets sloppy and executes rafs much rarely than it should`  Because your blocking the main thread, it's impossible for `requestAnimationFrame` to fire any events, if your blocking the event pump.  So explains why when you take out your blocking code it works.. Nothing strange here!!!..

Comment: @Keith look at the picture. The first raf is called after 10 timer cbs. There's 50 callbacks scheduled. How, do you think, this is possible if the main thread is blocked?

Comment: Timers use a queue.  Also, requestAnimationFrame uses a queue, but I would expect only for the current animation frame, seen as it's meant for animation.